# What could cause L20N to not process the Entity variables and inclusions?

Tags: mozilla, reactjs, l20n

[L20N](http://l20n.org/) is setup in my ReactJS project and I am calling `getSync` on the `context` *after* its `ready` event has fired (so things should be good to go).  However, rather than my expected string including other Entity values and variable expansion, I get the raw Entity string.

The string I get looks like this:

`{{$user.name}} - {{appName}}`

But of course, I'm expecting something like this:

`Ben Taylor - My Cool App`

I have tried to [recreate the problem in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IK0GcRTiNrAAw8yEdIU5).  Unfortunately, it works fine!  When you run it, the alert box shows the expected L20N expanded string.

**What could cause the Entity value to be returned raw?**  I have a valid `context` and there are no errors in inspector, so it appears all is configured fine.  I'm wondering if there is some interaction with something else I'm doing that is breaking L20N.  Any ideas appreciated!

*I am unable to include the app I'm working on, but needless to say it has more moving parts.  It is a React app based on [this template](https://github.com/tcoopman/react-es6-browserify).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is some sort of error in your `.l20n` file (the extension formerly known as `.lol`) then the `getSync` call will return the raw string value.  In my case the error was to *quote* the keys in an [L20n dictionary](http://l20n.org/learn/translations-with-multiple-variants/).

If you have `context` data like `{ user: { type: "Awesome" } }` then the following **does not work** and calling `getSync` for `useTheShout` will return the unprocessed string value (including the text `{{shout}}`):

```
<shout[$user.type] {
    "Awesome": "HEY AWESOME USER!",
    "Loser": "i can't be bothered to shout at you loser..."
}>
<useTheShout "I'm gonna shout the following: {{shout}}">
```

Removing the quote marks from the dictionary key names will make this work, as follows:

```
<shout[$user.type] {
    Awesome: "HEY AWESOME USER!",
    Loser: "i can't be bothered to shout at you loser..."
}>
<useTheShout "I'm gonna shout the following: {{shout}}">
```

**Update:  You can avoid the pain by logging using the `error` and `warning` [event emitters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/L20n/Javascript_API#ctx.addEventListener%28event.3A_String.2C_callback.3A_Function%29).**